# Class is not supported for deserialization of an array

Tags: c#, json

I get an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Type 'VK.Response' is not supported
>   for deserialization of an array.

JSON that i get looks like:

> {"response":[{"id":269058571,"first_name":"Name","last_name":"LastName","photo_50":"http://cs624717.vk.me/v624717571/21718/X8.jpg"}]}

My method is:

```
 private void getFriendInfo()
    {
        string method = "users.get";
        string param = "user_ids=269058571&fields=photo_50";
        string url = "https://api.vk.com/method/" + method + "?" + param + "&v=5.31&access_token=" + key + "";

        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        string json = client.DownloadString(url);
        JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        RootObject response = (RootObject)json_serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(RootObject));
        for (int counter = 0; counter < response.response.items.Count; counter++)
        {
            pictureBox1.Load(response.response.items[counter].photo_50);
        }
    }
```

Classes:

```
      class Response
        {
            public int count { get; set; }
            public List<Item> items { get; set; }
        }

       class RootObject
       {
            public Response response { get; set; }
       }
       class Item
       {
            public string first_name { get; set; }
            public string last_name { get; set; }
            public string domain { get; set; }
            public string photo_50 { get; set; }
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to declare your "RootObject" class like this:

```
class RootObject
       {
            public List<Response> response { get; set; }
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your object model does not line up w/ the json.
Try this instead (I am using Newtonsoft.Json which is the standard JSON lib nowadays instead of the one that comes w/ .Net)  Use nuget package manager to get it... https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = "{\"response\":[{\"id\":269058571,\"first_name\":\"Name\",\"last_name\":\"LastName\",\"photo_50\":\"http://cs624717.vk.me/v624717571/21718/X8.jpg\"}]}";

        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

        foreach(var item in obj.response) {
            Console.WriteLine(item.first_name);
        }           
    }
}

class RootObject
{
    public List<Item> response { get; set; }
}
class Item
{
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string domain { get; set; }
    public string photo_50 { get; set; }
}
```

Live example at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WJwvm3